# How to make Edit Text hint appear when typing

Tags: android, android-edittext

I would like for my app to be able to display different hints in the edittext at different times, so i have to set the hint pro-grammatically at each times as below.

```
editText.setHint("Hint 1");
```

But the problem is when i starts typing the hint starts disappearing.I want to show this hint every time.If i set the hint in xml it will not disappear while typing, but how to do this in my case.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, You should be using `TextInputLayout`. Enclose your `EditText` inside `TextInputLayout` in your layout xml file

Comment: @SripadRaj Yes I have that TextInputLayout for enclosing the EditText. My problem is as i dynamically changing the hint as per condition the hint gets disappear when the user types anything on the edittext. I always want to show this hint.

Comment: Is it possible without **TextInputLayout**?
Actually i already set hint programmatically and it's working good.
but now i want set text same way and issue was occur hint goes hide after setting the text.

Comment: @Arbaz.in the answer by Ravi Sahu looks good.I didn't tried it.Please try if u want to try.

Answer (score 4):

Either you should consider to change to [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html)(Strongly recommended this. [Here is an example too.](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Working-with-the-EditText#displaying-floating-label-feedback))

**or**

make relative layout with EditText for input and TextView for hint inside.Change the textview according to your needs.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some text"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_hint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="yourHint"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/customColor"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I like the first the approach u said,but the problem is the hint will show at the bottom of edittext and once u clear the entered text and then again entered any text the error will not be shown as hint

Answer (score 2):

what you are expecting is not possible,since we have to how what user is writing on editext.
Now a days https://github.com/hardik-trivedi/FloatingLabel
this type of hints are more popular,you can try above link.

Answer (score 1):

`TextInputLayout` give powerful material features to `EditText`. Main feature is floating hint. See doc here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't display while typing text in edit text **hint** in android have default functionality

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:hint="Email Address"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:translationY="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_13"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Here android provide default functionality while typing text in edit text the hint above edit text, You can also set Hint via programmatically

```
 EditText. setHint ("Hint 1");
```

Comment: If i set the hint in xml, while typing text in edit text the hint will show above edit text.If i do so this hint will become permenant and i can't change the hint anymore.If i used EditText. setHint ("Hint 1") then the hint will disappear when typing on the edittext.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do this is to use TextInputLayout.

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/becoming-material-with-android-design-support-library/

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!--EMAIL-->
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/email_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUserName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/login_screen_email_hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/etPassword"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And dont forget adding this line to your gradle file

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

Comment: I need to change the hint as per the dropdown selected entry.So how can i change the hint when i change the dropdown item if i set the hint in xml??

Comment: So you just have to use support design up to 22.2.1,
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1.
and ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserName)).setHint('bla bla');

before 22.2.1 it was a known bug :
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175228&q=TextInputLayout&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars